# Table-cell with width in %

Tags: html, css

I've got three different `table-cell` divs which have different widths: `30%`, `40%` and `30%`.

My outer div is `100%`, but my inner divs doesn't displayed as they should be. If I am using `px` it works fine (Example: outer div:`300px`, inner:`100px` each).

So how can I make it work with width also? [Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/LWBQ3/)

```css
#container { width:100%; background:#ccc; }
#left { background:red; width:30%; display:table-cell; }
#center { background:green; width:40%; display:table-cell;  }
#right { background:red; width:30%; display:table-cell;  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">asdasdas  </div>
    <div id="center">as das da <p> asdas </p> </div>
    <div id="left"> asd as das</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require them to cover full width then set the `display` property of `#container` to `table`.

```css
#container { width:100%; background:#ccc; display:table; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWBQ3/2/)**.

If you do not require them to cover full width but the `container` to be as big as the inner divs then set it to `table-row`

```css
#container { width:100%; background:#ccc; display:table-row; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LWBQ3/5/)**.